# Object tracking of fast moving small objects

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolov5, video-tracking

I have a task to count small objects falling freely from conveyor exit using camera. Camera input will be like as shown in this video below, and I need to count them.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nKzDVLBZmpdQDIsiNU1BwiwKKPdm-dHo/view

I was thinking to go for object detection using Yolo and then apply DeepSort for tracking and counting.

I have two simple questions regarding this.

1. Is it good to use Yolo detection for such fast moving object problem or is it a bad approach. And if it's not right, what approach would you suggest me?
2. Secondly, I don't have image dataset available, I only have these below videos, which I'm thinking to extract frames from and label them for object detection. But the issue is if you check the video, the video quality is quite poor so the frames from video doesn't show objects clearly for annotations.
   (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yCNu-1ViXYlqWBlKqzxWtXBueYXgmlXS/view?usp=share_link)
   (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nKzDVLBZmpdQDIsiNU1BwiwKKPdm-dHo/view?usp=share_link)

Is there any solution to above problems. And what should be the approach and methods to count such fast moving small objects?

Any help of any kind will be very appreciated :)

Comment: If all you need to do is count objects falling, you can do much simpler than Deep Learning. I haven’t looked at the video, but I can’t imagine this being a difficult problem. If it is, you should adjust illumination and background to make it simple. That is much cheaper than building and maintaining a complex computer program. Also, this problem has always been solved just fine using a single optical detector (light on one side, detector on the other, falling objects interrupt light to provide the signal), you don’t need a camera for this at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you pause the video on any of the frames you all the moving objects are smeared out on the image. Your camera is your main issue here. My suggestion is that you first get a camera with a higher shutter speed so that the moving objects appear sharper. Then, collect a dataset, annotate and train Yolo.

Feel free to checkout out my tracking repo: https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/Yolov5_StrongSORT_OSNet